# Measuring network packets inter-arrival times

Tags: networking

I want to get the inter-arrival times of the network packets. I want to use these arrival times for predicting the arrival time of future packet (probably by using Bayesian classifier). Can someone suggest how can I get the inter-arrival times of incoming packets? I don't see any such option in wireshark. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`pcap`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) (packet capture) API should allow you to get this information.

Here is some example code: [link](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html).

Comment: The example code pointed out by you runs fine, but it captures both incoming and outgoing packets. What I need is the only incoming packets to my host PC. Since _wireshark_ and _tcpdump_ are also doing the same, I want to set a filter only to get the incoming packets. How can I set such a filter?

Comment: I found the answer of my question. The filter can be set as ip.dst== _ip_host_address_